# How to create image file and mount via. loopback (Ubuntu to remote backup space)

Tags: ubuntu, backup, rsync, loopback, rsnapshot

I've been fiddling around with the Hetzner Backup Space and I want to use rsync via. rsnapshot in order to back up my files (more info at [their Wiki here](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Backup/en#Accessing_Backup_Space))

They state in their documentation:

> The direct use of rsync is not possible. Backup space can, however, be locally 
>   mounted using smbfs, sshfs or ftpfs, which allows a limited use of
>   rsync. To take full advantage of rsync (such as incremental backups
>   using hardlinks) an image file must be created, which should be
>   mounted via loopback. In addition to this, it is also possible to add
>   encryption via encfs (Encrypted File System) to protect the data.

I've already given it a stab by using Curlftpfs and, well, as it was to be expected that doesn't work very well - I get hangs and timeouts and a plethora of errors.

I would like to try the more "correct" way of solving this as described by the quote above - but how do I actually accomplish this? I've tried googling the matter, but the information out there is conflicting and confusing.

Encryption is not a must-have for me. I just want something that works, the simpler the better :)

Comment: In your quote you omit the header: **This procedure is experimental and therefore not officially supported** so that's probably not the solution you'd want to when you *"want something that works, the simpler the better"*

Comment: @HBruijn I see your point, however I'd like to give it a go before ruling it out, as they indicate that this is the way to go with rsync incremental backups. Dumping data over ftp does not seem to be the way forward for me.

Comment: And the alternative they recommend: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Tartarus_Backup-Konfiguration/en ?